# QGIS adding world shore line buffer zone but dashes appear. How can I remove them?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am trying to add buffer one to the world shoreline. However, when I zoom out, some unintended straight lines show up. When I zoom in, those lines disappear. This line does not exist.

[image]

How can I prevent lines from appearing on the screen?

Comment: Please tell us more about your shoreline data:  what is its source?  What Coordinate Reference System is it in?  Can you make it available to others for their review?

Comment: Looks like a plain vanilla "buffer across the dateline" issue.

Comment: Dear Stu Smith an d Vince, Thank you so much. A little hint helped me find the answer. I just changed the coordinate system, and the issue is solved.

Comment: For future people who have the same question, it would be helpful if you placed your solution in the "Your Answer" pane below.  Please be specific, including what did not work (such as defining your old coordinate system) and the solution (the new coordinate system values).  Welcome to SE-GIS!

Comment: Thank you for your nice reminder.  Initially, the WGS84 Web Mercator Auxilary Sphere was chosen. Later, I changed the WGS84, and the problem was solved.